# Generate rows before and after selected row from jsonb column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select, jsonb

I want to ask for help because I can't solve this problem.
I have this result which is correct. But it is the result of real physical data that are in the table.

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY PR."Priority") AS "LOS", "SpeedLessThan", "SpeedAtLeast"
 FROM "ProjectRules" PR
 WHERE PR."ProjectId" = 500
   AND PR."Group" = 1;
```

[image]

Well, the problem is, now I have a different structure where the physical line is JSON. And the result of this query is this.

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY MQ."Id") AS "LOS", "LevelOfServiceConfig"
 FROM "ProjectMqs" MQ
 WHERE MQ."ProjectId" = 500 AND "Id" = 1;
```

[image]

I need to generate a result that will be exactly the same as the result above. So this one row is split into 3 rows and its value is either less to zero or more to 999.

```
SELECT "Id" as "LOS", "LevelOfServiceConfig" ->> 'Danger' AS "Danger", "LevelOfServiceConfig" ->> 'TrafficJam' AS "TrafficJam"
FROM "ProjectMqs"
WHERE "ProjectId" = 500
  AND NULLIF(regexp_replace("Name", '\D','','g'), '')::numeric = 1;
```

I don't know what to do with this query to get the result.

Comment: Hi there. Could you post the exact expected result for the second picture with the json record?

Comment: You want to insert the values Danger and Traffic jam as a new column in first table?

Comment: Hi @JimJones I would like to achieve exactly the result as in picture 1. But i have only this ( "{"Danger": 70, "TrafficJam": 35}")  That is, what I have in picture 2. The line "{"Danger": 70, "TrafficJam": 35}" is like the middle row in picture 1. And generate the line below and above line. So row 1 and row 3. Let's say I already have row 2.

Comment: Very simply put, imagine we only have json column and in 1 row, "{"Danger": 70, "TrafficJam": 35}" and you want to have exactly what is in picture 1.

Comment: I have 
"SpeedLessThan" "SpeedAtLeast"
65, 35

I want to have 
"SpeedLessThan" "SpeedAtLeast"
999,65
65, 35,
35, 0

Comment: @SalmanA yes, and also generate row above and below that. The way how to made columns from that, that's something what i know. Problem is to generate that values before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to create one row, just use `UNION ALL` or a similar construct to create the three rows:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v.SpeedAtLeast) AS LOS, v.*
FROM t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES
    (999, (t.LevelOfServiceConfig->>'Danger')::int),
    ((t.LevelOfServiceConfig->>'Danger')::int, (t.LevelOfServiceConfig->>'TrafficJam')::int),
    ((t.LevelOfServiceConfig->>'TrafficJam')::int, 0)
) AS v(SpeedLessThan, SpeedAtLeast)
ORDER BY LOS
```

Comment: This is incredible, thank you for the speed. It works exactly as I imagined. Thank you again and have a nice day.